# VAT won't add to final checkout

Tags: magento2.2, tax, vat, magento2.2.3, tax-calculation

The tax won't process even if everything is set correctly. Magento 2.2.3
  ![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RGqz.png
  ![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKcXz.png
  ![3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN4QN.png